# How to get the position that the PDF outline points to, using Apache PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, groovy, pdfbox

I would like to get the position that the PDF outline points to, using Apache PDFBOX, for a groovy script.

This Groovy Script is to get annotations and separate them into outlines, but when there is more than one outline pointing to the same page I don't know to which outline the annotation belongs. When I get the annotations I have the quadpoints, they gave me the Y-axis position in the page, I would like to get something similar for the position that the outlines point.

For annotations I use `COSArray quadsArray = (COSArray) current.getCOSObject().getCOSArray(COSName.QUADPOINTS);` to get the position in the page, but for the outline I get null.

```java
public getBookmarkItem(PDOutlineNode bookmark, Integer indentation, bookmarksArray, thisDoc) {
    Integer destPage = 0
    PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
    indentation+=1;
    while (current != null) {
        def bookmarksMap = [page:destPage,level:0,title:'',pagePosition:0] 
        def destPageObj = current.findDestinationPage(thisDoc);
        def count=0
        for( PDPage pdfpage : thisDoc.getPages() ) {
            count+=1;
            if (pdfpage == destPageObj) {
                destPage=count;
                break;
            }
        }
        COSArray quadsArray = (COSArray) current.getCOSObject().getCOSArray(COSName.QUADPOINTS);
        println quadsArray.toString()

        bookmarksMap.page=destPage;
        bookmarksMap.level=indentation;
        bookmarksMap.title=current.getTitle();
        bookmarksArray << bookmarksMap;
        println "DESTINATION for " + bookmarksMap.title + ": " + destPage
        getBookmarkItem(current, indentation, bookmarksArray, thisDoc);
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}

public getBookmarks(PDDocument thisDoc) {
    println "> Pegando Bookmarks"
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = thisDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDDocumentOutline docOutline = docCatalog.getDocumentOutline();
    def bookmarksArray = []
    if (docOutline != null) {
        getBookmarkItem(docOutline, 0, bookmarksArray, thisDoc);
    }
    println ">> Bookmarks pegos: " + bookmarksArray
    return bookmarksArray
}
```

Comment: Outlines don't have quadpoints, or did I miss something? I know quadpoints from certain annotations.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought outlines had quadpoints. But, they have something similar, how can I get the outline position in the page? I need this to know to wich outline the annotation belongs.

Comment: If you're still interested in this, you should consider updating the question with what you said in your comments, merely with more detail.

Comment: I missed the April 13 comment. Outlines and annotations are different things. Outlines don't have a position, but they may point to a page and position by their action or destination. See the `PrintBookmarks.java` example from the source code download.

Comment: I changed the title and description to make more clear, thanks for the suggestions.